# Overheating of 100uF, 50v electrolytic capacitor

Tags: power

I have an electrolytic capacitor I replaced from a rechargeable lantern but this capacitor keep on overheating until is blown. I am sure the polarity is correct because the body is "marked" and the value 100uF, 50v at 85 degree Celsius temperature same as the original one. can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.
I appreciate your responses.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes a photo of the circuitry could be helpful.

Comment: The fact that you needed to replace the capacitor in the first place means that the design is a crappy one. I mean, the device could be using the capacitor in the wrong way, stressing it and making it fail. Replacing the capacitor again and again doesn't solve that.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Well, it could be a competent design but a crappy capacitor, and the replacement was selected poorly.

Comment: `I inserted in the negatively mark screen` .... the picture does not show that

Comment: I think we need more than just a crappy circuit board picture. What have you done, really? How did you knew in the first place you needed to change the capacitor? Maybe some other component were broken and did put an high voltage at the cap's terminals, making it fail. Also, did you measure any voltage or current (particularly, what's the voltage on the capacitor)? By looking at the circuit board so far, my assessment would be a broken resistor, because it is dark right under it (looks like it burned), on the PCB (the smallest resistor), could you test it with a ohmmeter?

Comment: Yea the resistor and capacitor got burnt. I have changed both the resistor and the capacitor. Resistor is just Ik. the brown out under the resistor is as a result of the initial burnt before I changed them

Comment: just an image to illustrate my initial question

Comment: Measure the other resistors, then, and the diodes (the other cap could be measured, too).

Answer (score 3):

More than likely you put it in backwards. The minus is marked on electrolytic capacitors. Show us a photo to be sure.

Photo from [here](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/capacitors/electrolytic.php)

[image]

As well as the markings, usually the positive lead is longer (unless it's been trimmed).

---

If it really isn't the most likely reason, we may need a schematic. It's possible that the capacitor has to be a **low-ESR type** because it's in a switching power supply. We may be able to tell by looking at a photo of **each side** of the PCB, or  not.

If the capacitor is not low-impedance and is in a circuit with high **ripple current**, it can overheat and fail in short order.

Low impedance capacitors had [massive problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague) some years ago due to counterfeit electrolyte used by some major manufacturers. A lot of motherboards were affected. New ones purchased through reputable distributors (not eBay, Ali, garage sale, Kijiji, Craig's List etc.) should be okay.

Comment: I will upload the circuit help please

Comment: I added the photo, please delete the duplicate question. The circuit looks like a (dodgy) mains-powered dropping capacitor charger. I don't see the polarity marking on the PCB. It's possible something else is wrong such as  a shorted diode or open zener diode. Hard to tell.

Comment: Of course, it is not unknown for the PCB silk screen to show the wrong polarity.

Comment: @AndrewMorton has a good point. If this didn't look so lethal I would suggest you measure it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming correct polarity, a low ESR cap or high ripple current rating is needed as well as equal or high C,V rating.  Heat is caused by \$Pd=ESR*Irms^2\$. The best are Japanese brands with stated specs to exceed application.

[**e.g**](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/epcos-tdk/B41858C9107M000/495-6039-ND/3544149). $1

This design should use same C value to establish voltage ratio with line input rectified and series plastic cap (brown). Due to offline charge pump to lower voltage, current pulses are much higher than load.

The example I gave should work.